# How can I pull a table's column list via GridConfiguration similar to how it's done in regular SQL?

Tags: sql, azure, azure-synapse

I encountered an SQL query structured this way. The code snippet was given to me without explanation so I'm at a loss on where to proceed. The query works but I would like to expand on it. (Also, probably the wrong flair but this is being run on a Azure Synapse.)

question: how do I get an entire table's column list? Also, is there a way to explore the tables from this database similar to SMSS so that I have a better idea on how the data is structured? Some of the column names have HTML tags on them (this is data coming from a webform).

The query:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    OPENROWSET (
            PROVIDER = 'provider',
            CONNECTION = 'Account=account;Database=database',
            OBJECT = 'GridConfiguration',
            SERVER_CREDENTIAL = 'server-cred'
        )
WITH    (
            "Created Date" varchar(256),
            "<p>ClientId</p>" varchar(max),
            -- other columns
        ) AS [GridConfiguration]`
```

I've already tried different variations of the column names (with and without HTML tags, with and without a space after the terminating paragraph tag) but I'm ending up with just null values so I figure I'm not getting the correct column name, or this dataset was curated by someone else.

Comment: Where you are performing this in dedicated SQL pool or Serverless pool?

Comment: It's from the Built-in Serverless Pool

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK OPENROWSET is used for access data from azure blob storage.
I loaded the data from azure blob storage to SQL serverless pool by following below procedure.
I created External data source using below code:

```
CREATE  EXTERNAL  DATA  SOURCE [ExternalDataSource] WITH
(
   LOCATION = 'https://<storageaccount>.blob.core.windows.net/<container>'
)
```

Image for reference:

[image]

I created External file format using below code:

```
CREATE  EXTERNAL  FILE  FORMAT [ExternalFileFormat] WITH
(
      FORMAT_TYPE = DELIMITEDTEXT
)
```

Image for reference:

[image]

I created external table using below code:

```
CREATE  EXTERNAL  TABLE [dbo].[ExternalTable1]
(
     SalesNumber int,StoreShortName varchar(20),NetSales int, 
     GrossMargin int,NetSales1 int,SalesTrend int
) 
WITH
(
   LOCATION = 'Folder/File',
   DATA_SOURCE = [ExternalDataSource],
   FILE_FORMAT = [ExternalFileFormat]
)
```

I fetched list of table columns and it's details using below code:

```
sp_columns  <tableName>
```

Image for reference:

[image]

In this way I retrieved all columns and it's details.
If you want load data from any sql server AFAIK linked connection is the best option.
Image for reference:

[image]

Note: It performs under dedicated SQL pool.